# how to push one item into array with 15 objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
var array1 = [{
  "candidateId": 57,
  "firstName": "Sumit",
  "lastName": "Kumar Gupta",
  "displayName": "Sumit1",
  "locked": false,
  "photoId": -1,
  "resumeId": -1,
  "experience": " 6 Months",
  "email": "sumit1@test.com",
  "mobile": "+91.8100688592",
  "preferredLocation": [
    "Bangalore"
  ],
  "currentEmployer": [

  ],
  "skills": [{
    "skillName": "JAVA",
    "level": "advanced",
    "candidateRating": "5",
    "rating": 0
  }],
  "viewed": true,
  "nextStates": [{
    "state": "Approach"
  }]]


var array2 = [image1]
```

I am getting `array2` images from other request so I assigned into `array2`. Now I wanted to push or add this `array2` into `array1`. So I created an object

```
'image'  
array2.push({'image':image1})
```

and tried pushing

```
for(var i=0; i<array1.length;i++){
  array1[i].push(array2[i]);
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you attempting to map two arrays with equal lengths where an object from each respective index position is to be merged?

Comment: So how does the logic work for mapping the image array to array1? Are all of the images added to each object in array1?

Comment: yes . It should be added to each object .the length of array 1 will be equal to array 2.Sorry for previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array1[i]['image'] = image1;` or `array1[i].image = image1;`

You need to add your image object to array1 value using property accessors.

***DEMO***

```js
var array1 = [{
 "candidateId": 57,
 "firstName": "Sumit",
 "lastName": "Kumar Gupta",
 "displayName": "Sumit1",
 "locked": false,
 "photoId": -1,
 "resumeId": -1,
 "experience": " 6 Months",
 "email": "sumit1@test.com",
 "mobile": "+91.8100688592",
 "preferredLocation": [
   "Bangalore"
 ],
 "currentEmployer": [

 ],
 "skills": [{
   "skillName": "JAVA",
   "level": "advanced",
   "candidateRating": "5",
   "rating": 0
 }],
 "viewed": true,
 "nextStates": [{
   "state": "Approach"
 }]
}]

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
 array1[i]['image'] = 'image1';
}
console.log(array1)
```

Comment: it doesnt work . my array1 doesnt have object image. so does it will work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to map two arrays with equal lengths where an object from each respective index position is to be merged then you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over one of the arrays and use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to shallow copy and merge the objects. This approach will help prevent side effects if either input array needs to be left unmodified.

The code would be:

```
array1.map((obj, i) => ({...obj, image: array2[i]}));
```

And the a demo:

```js
var array1 = [{
  "candidateId": 57,
  "firstName": "Sumit",
  "lastName": "Kumar Gupta",
  "displayName": "Sumit1",
  "locked": false,
  "photoId": -1,
  "resumeId": -1,
  "experience": " 6 Months",
  "email": "sumit1@test.com",
  "mobile": "+91.8100688592",
  "preferredLocation": [
    "Bangalore"
  ],
  "currentEmployer": [

  ],
  "skills": [{
    "skillName": "JAVA",
    "level": "advanced",
    "candidateRating": "5",
    "rating": 0
  }],
  "viewed": true,
  "nextStates": [{
    "state": "Approach"
  }]
}];


var array2 = ["image1"];

var combined = array1.map((obj, i) => ({...obj, image: array2[i]}));

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access way more indexes in array two than there are available.

try:

```
for(var i=0; i<array1.length;i++){
  array1[i].push(array2[0]);
}
```